# CMS in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, content-management-system

How can I create a **CMS** in asp.net just like **wordpress**. I didn't find any tutorial about this. Can you guys please provide me some link related to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you create your own CMS, when other standard open source CMS are present. I would simply use them.

Comment: @GaganDeep - It's only for learning purpose

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need it for learning purposes but what about if you check out an open source project based on ASP.NET? Have a look at DotNetNuke. The code is also available on github.

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform

Answer (score 0):

Creating a complete and large `CMS` like WordPress is a hard work to do. Check out the [aspnetboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) which is an awesome framework that has been created upon `Asp.Net` and is open source. Take a look at its [source code](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) and check out its website and see how it works. Reading and learning from it is a great help.

There are also other great frameworks to look at. [DNN](https://github.com/masoudarvishian/Dnn.Platform) and [NopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce) are also wonderful.